# How to create double range slider using native html input range and Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, slider, range

Can you please help me with creating a double range slider (I only need two handles) for the native HTML input=range and Vue.js?

My code so far:
https://jsfiddle.net/

Javascript (Vue.js)

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    minAngle: 10,
    maxAngle: 30
  },
  computed: {
    sliderMin: {
      get: function() {
        var val = this.minAngle;
        return val;
      },
      set: function(val) {
        if (val > this.maxAngle) {
          val = this.maxAngle;
        }
        this.minAngle = val;
        console.log("minAngle:" + this.minAngle + " maxAngle:" + this.maxAngle);
      }
    },
    sliderMax: {
      get: function() {
        var val = this.maxAngle;
        return val;
      },
      set: function(val) {
        if (val < this.minAngle) {
          val = this.minAngle;
        }
        this.maxAngle = val;
        console.log("minAngle:" + this.minAngle + " maxAngle:" + this.maxAngle);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="app">
  <input type="range" min="0" max="180" step="1" v-model="sliderMin">
  <input type="number" min="0" max="180" step="1" v-model="sliderMin">
  <input type="range" min="0" max="180" step="1" v-model="sliderMax">
  <input type="number" min="0" max="180" step="1" v-model="sliderMax">
</div>
```

The problem is that I would like to limit the range of the minSlider and the maxSlider if their values come below the min. So you would not get the maxAngle be below the minAngle or minAngle be above the maxAngle. Later I will of course make one slider on the top of each other using CSS so you will get the illusion it is only one slider with two handles. I know that there are Vue components for this but I was wondering if this is possible.

Thanks in advance,
Bogdan

Comment: I realized that variables were sometimes strings instead of numbers. So I updated the code. Now it doesn't have that bugs when dragging the slider handles but it would be nice if it stopped at a certain value (being that maxAngle or minAngle). Here is the latest fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bogdanb86/3dr9ktxc/16/

Comment: It seems it does not support `decimal` values. Do you have an example code that does? Also, the part of the track that is outside the min and max, does your implementation support coloring that a different gray color for example?

Answer (score 12):

Nevermind, I found out the solution. I turned out that I was not far away :)
Here it is:

HTML

```
<div id="app">
  <div class='range-slider'>
    <input type="range" min="0" max="180" step="1" v-model="sliderMin">
    <input type="number" min="0" max="180" step="1" v-model="sliderMin">
    <input type="range" min="0" max="180" step="1" v-model="sliderMax">
    <input type="number" min="0" max="180" step="1" v-model="sliderMax">
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript (Vue)

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    minPrice: "500",
    maxPrice: "50000",
    minValue: "25000"
  },
  methods: {
    slider: function() {
      if (this.minPrice > this.maxPrice) {
        var tmp = this.maxPrice;
        this.maxPrice = this.minPrice;
        this.minPrice = tmp;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

CSS

```
.range-slider {
  width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  height: 6em;
}

.range-slider input[type=range] {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

input[type=number] {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}

input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

input[type=number]:invalid,
input[type=number]:out-of-range {
  border: 2px solid #ff6347;
}

input[type=range] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
}

input[type=range]:focus {
  outline: none;
}

input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: #2497e3;
}

input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: #2497e3;
}

input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: #2497e3;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  animate: 0.2s;
  background: #2497e3;
  border-radius: 1px;
  box-shadow: none;
  border: 0;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000;
  border: 1px solid #2497e3;
  height: 18px;
  width: 18px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: #a1d0ff;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin-top: -7px;
}
```

Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/bogdanb86/3dr9ktxc/28/