# Create a dragable balls on a line in react js

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a video of a draggable balls on a line. I have to implement the functionality in react js. The balls are draggable and move across the line [image]
after release the ball stick to its position not move to its original position.

I have tried multiple codes and approaches but none of them works as needed. I need help to create such feature in react, please help me if someone knows how to do it.

```
const Ball = ({ color, onDragStart, onDragOver, onDrop }) => (
       <div
         className="ball"
         draggable
         onDragStart={onDragStart}
         onDragOver={onDragOver}
         onDrop={onDrop}
         style={{ backgroundColor: color }}
      />
     );


     import React, { useState } from 'react';
     import Ball from './Ball';

     const colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow'];

     const Line = () => {
     const [balls, setBalls] = useState(colors);

     const onDragStart = (e, index) => {
     e.dataTransfer.setData('index', index);
      };

      const onDragOver = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      };

      const onDrop = (e, index) => {
    const droppedIndex = e.dataTransfer.getData('index');
    const newBalls = [...balls];
    newBalls.splice(droppedIndex, 1);
    newBalls.splice(index, 0, colors[droppedIndex]);
    setBalls(newBalls);
  };

  return (
    <div className="line">
      {balls.map((color, index) => (
        <Ball
          key={index}
          color={color}
          onDragStart={(e) => onDragStart(e, index)}
          onDragOver={onDragOver}
          onDrop={(e) => onDrop(e, index)}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

this code is not working.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create multiple range slide handles in one slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368206/create-multiple-range-slide-handles-in-one-slider)

Comment: or [How to create double range slider using native html input range and Vue.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61871010/how-to-create-double-range-slider-using-native-html-input-range-and-vue-js)

Answer (score 0):

```
     const Ball = ({ color, onDragStart, onDragOver, onDrop }) => (
       <div
         className="ball"
         draggable
         onDragStart={onDragStart}
         onDragOver={onDragOver}
         onDrop={onDrop}
         style={{ backgroundColor: color }}
      />
     );


     import React, { useState } from 'react';
     import Ball from './Ball';

     const colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow'];

     const Line = () => {
     const [balls, setBalls] = useState(colors);

     const onDragStart = (e, index) => {
     e.dataTransfer.setData('index', index);
      };

      const onDragOver = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      };

      const onDrop = (e, index) => {
    const droppedIndex = e.dataTransfer.getData('index');
    const newBalls = [...balls];
    newBalls.splice(droppedIndex, 1);
    newBalls.splice(index, 0, colors[droppedIndex]);
    setBalls(newBalls);
  };

  return (
    <div className="line">
      {balls.map((color, index) => (
        <Ball
          key={index}
          color={color}
          onDragStart={(e) => onDragStart(e, index)}
          onDragOver={onDragOver}
          onDrop={(e) => onDrop(e, index)}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```